# При вводе в input чисел нужно чтобы они разбивались на разряды.

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как обрабатывать value input, чтобы числа бились на разряды?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбил на пробел, можно заменить на запятую

```js
function discharge(){
  $('input').val(String($('input').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));
}
discharge();
$('input').keyup(function(){
  discharge();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="12345847">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось)